# Cannot open Word document with Math Equations

Tags: microsoft-word

After writing an a math document in Word and saving the document for a week or Moore  and trying to go back to the document to modify the math equations I get the following message:
"The server application, source file or item cannot be found.
Make sure the application is properly installed, and that it has not been deleted, moved, renamed or blocked by policy."
Any advice on solving this problem!
I have tried various file formats, Like Word Template,... and still go through the same error.
Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be confused about some computer related things; please find a local PC-knowledgeable person to help you - your problem description does not make sense.

Comment: That error message is not about the file, but is about a program. How are you trying to open this document? Where is the error message being show? What is the path to the document?